# How you create and display the section headers in landscape orientation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewcelleditcontrol

This is my current behaviour

[image: current behaviour]

I want the **"More"** section header leading to be aligned with the tableview cells leading. When in portrait they all are at same leading space but, in landscape orientation the section header is not at same leading as the tableview cells.

Want to achieve this.

[image: Required behaviour]

I don't see anything going wrong but, when in landscape the headers are not aligning to the cells. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this:

I have previously set the leading of tableView to superView leading but, it should be set with safeArea leading. Which solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is this :--

Recently
**More**. header leading, is from superview and cell leading is from safe area.

so you need to change leading of header view "**More**."  *superview to safe area*

you need to use **sizeclass** for autolayout constraint for lanscap and portraint view